# Besides armed insurrection what other resistance was offered by American slaves?

Tags: united-states, slavery

Watching Birth of a Nation about Nat Turner's revolt which as far as I can tell was doomed to failure but would, for example, Blacks running for the frontier when most of the USA was unsettled been considered?

EDIT: I am aware of Underground RR but what I meant was, a large force of slaves rather than attacking attempting to leave en masse, protected by their numbers.

Comment: Go watch [Slavery - Crash Course US History](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ajn9g5Gsv98), at about 7.20 it starts to cover slave resistance. I know this isn't what you're looking for, but the first thing it discusses is small scale resistance to the dehumanization of slavery, like marriage, religion and literacy. At 10.35 it starts to talk about more direct resistance.

Comment: Your title question is acceptable, but you get into hypotheticals with the speculation, which is off-topic and will likely draw close votes.

Comment: @user2448131: I am not really sure what the goal is but if it requires close study of some rules or one *risks having their question closed* then I am guessing that you will limit the participation to some very tolerant questioners. I think you should worry more about answers than honest questions, irrespective of what you call speculation.

Comment: @Jeff: History is about what happened, who made it happen, and why it happened. Not about what *could* have happened. You can try Worldbuilding.SE for the what-if's.

Comment: How would their numbers protect them more if they were fleeing than if they were fighting? For most of them, the "free" states were too far away, and leaving *en masse* made concealment impossible. Not to mention that after the Fugitive Slave Act they would not have been safe even in the "free" states.

Comment: The North is very unlikely to have reacted well to a large group of slaves arriving en masse asking for freedom even before the Fugitive Slave Act.

Comment: American slaves were treated like helots in ancient Sparta.

Comment: Not quite like helots, i don't think.

Answer (score 2):

> a large force of slaves

The answer to your question is found right there.  White slave owners knew that "a large force of slaves" was a dangerous thing.  They took action to ensure that slaves could not organize.

> 1680 - Virginia’s General Assembly restricts the ability of slaves to meet at gatherings, including funerals. It becomes legal for a white person or person to kill an escaped slave who resists capture. *[Colonial Williamsburg](http://www.history.org/history/teaching/slavelaw.cfm)* (hat tip to the scholar [user2448131](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/16951/user2448131); I'm ashamed to  have missed this.)

As a matter of fact, I believe the last time I visited Williamsburg, the courthouse was trying the case of a slave who was arrested for violating this ordinance; the slave had stopped to listen to a street preacher, and unwittingly exceeded the number of slaves who were permitted to gather.

Pretty much throughout history, criminal activity takes place in small groups; every additional member added to the group raises the risk of discovery, prosecution and execution.  Given that slaves were property, and by definition had no civil rights, slaveholders had a wide variety of extreme measures available to suppress any attempt to organize slaves.

If I were a slave and wanted to escape, I would know that my success was based on how ***few*** people knew of my plans.  I would not participate in any action by a large group of slaves.

The logistics of organizing slaves are staggering.

By coincidence the next day I heard [Patrick Breen discuss Nat Turner's](http://traffic.cast.plus/58f651031b4ea405fdc429e7/traffic.libsyn.com/benfranklinsworld/133_Breen.mp3?dest-id=218407) revolt - both professor Breen and Ms. Covart repeatedly reference the difficulty presented in organizing collective slave activity.